# Mean Stack: How can I store image in mongodb with nodejs expressjs and angular 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am building a MEAN Shop App, trying to store the product image in mongodb but some error is coming

`typeError: cannot read the property 'productimage' of undefined`

This is the route function for adding product

```js
function addProduct(req, res, next){
    var newProduct = new Product({
        productName: req.body.productname,
        productCategory: req.body.productcategory,
        productDescription: req.body.productdescription,
        productPrice: req.body.productprice
        });
    
    newProduct.productImage.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.productimage);
    newProduct.productImage.contentType = 'jpg';
    
     newProduct.save(function(err){
            if(err){ 
                console.log("error saving product");
                res.status(400).json({ 
                    success: false, 
                    message:'Error processing request '+ err});
        }
        else{
            console.log("product inserted");
            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
  message: 'Product added successfully.'
        });
    }
    });
}
module.exports = {addProduct);
```

This is the product model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  productname : { type: String },
  productCategory: { type: String },
  productDescription: { type: String },
  productImage: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
  productPrice: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('product', productSchema, 'products');
```

This is the html file

```html
<form class="form-style-9" 
       [formGroup]="productForm"
      (ngSubmit)="addProduct(productForm.value)"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
    <ul>
        <li><span>Product Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="productname" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Name" formControlName="productname" />
        </li>
        <span>Product Category</span><br>
        <select formControlName="productcategory">
          <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
          <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
          <option value="Books">Books</option>
          <option value="Toys">Toys</option>
        </select>
        <li><span>Product Description</span>
            <textarea name="productdescription" class="field-style" placeholder="Product Description" formControlName="productdescription"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li><span>Product Image</span>
            <input type="file" name="productimage" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Image" formControlName="productimage"/>
        </li>
        <li><span>Product Price</span>
            <input type="number" name="productprice" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Product Price" formControlName="productprice" />
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

this is component file

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private router: Router,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  productName = new FormControl("");
  productCategory = new FormControl("");
  productDescription = new FormControl("");
  productImage = new FormControl("");
  productPrice = new FormControl("");
  
  
  productForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    'productname': this.productName,
    'productcategory': this.productCategory,
    'productdescription': this.productDescription,
    'productimage': this.productImage,
    'productprice': this.productPrice,
  });
  
  addProduct(formdata:any) {
      this.productService.addProduct(this.productForm.value)
      .subscribe(data => {
          if (data.success === false) {
            this.toastr.error(data.message);
          } else {
            this.toastr.success(data.message);
            this.router.navigate([' ']);
          }
          this.productForm.reset();
      });
    }
  
}
```

I tried using **`multer`** but i dont think its working or may be i am coding it wrong. Please correct me what am i doing wrong.

I had created a different folder for storing image `server/public/images`, this is the same folder that contains routes and models `server/models/` and `server/routes/`.

This is the server file.

```js
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

var api = require('./server/routes/api');
var image = multer({ dest:'./server/public/' });

app.post('/product', image.single('images'), api.addProduct);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is that error coming from exactly? Node should give you a traceback to where it originated

Comment: it is coming from the route function while storing product information., from this line `newProduct.productImage.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.productimage);`

Comment: AFAIK you need to use `FormData` to send files via ajax. Are you sure the file is even sent?

Comment: Is this correct? `module.exports = {addProduct);`

Comment: yes everything is working but while clicking the add product button it is showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your multer configuration.
Can you share your require's and multer middleware as well.

Also I have included a sample configuration below to configure your multer middleware.

```js
const multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './path/to/file')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "PDFS-"+file.originalname.substring(0, file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' +   Date.now()+(path.extname(file.originalname)).toLowerCase())
  }
});
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    var ext = (path.extname(file.originalname)).toLowerCase();
    if(ext !== '.pdf') {
        return callback(new Error('Only pdf format files are allowed!'))
    }
    callback(null, true)
  },
  limits:{
      fileSize: 1024*1024
  }
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){
    upload.single('productimage')(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("upload err"+err);
          res.render('upload');
          return;
        }
        else{
        if (req.file===undefined) {
        console.log("empty");
        res.render('upload');
        } 
        else{
          console.log("done");
          res.render('upload');
        }
       }
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is the middleware i am using `var multer = require('multer'); var storage = multer.diskStorage({ destination: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, './server/public/images') }, filename: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()) } }); var upload = multer({storage: storage});`

Comment: Is your static directory server? because the path used in multer destination has to be relative from root, so if you have public as the static directory then the path should be: destination: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, './public/images')

Comment: Is it an issue using middlewares? as i am using both `body parser` and `multer`.

Comment: You need to make the public folder static.